# OpenCV can't find ffmpeg (?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, ffmpeg, camera

I can't get OpenCV to use FFMpeg for capturing webcam or video playback. (Windows, C++)

I downloaded [latest OpenCV 4.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.1.0/opencv-4.1.0-vc14_vc15.exe) and set it up in Visual Studio. It basically compiles and runs.

As far as I can see, the OpenCV I downloaded is build with FFMpeg (?).

I just want to capture my webcam:

```
VideoCapture capture;

capture.open(0);
if (!capture.isOpened()) return;

Mat frame;
while (capture.read(frame))
{
    if (frame.empty()) {
        cout << "frame empty" << endl;
    }
    imshow("capture", frame);
}
capture.release();
destroyAllWindows();
return 0;
```

the result I get is:

```
[ INFO:0] VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(6, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); MSMF(980); DSHOW(970); CV_IMAGES(960); CV_MJPEG(950)
[ INFO:0] VideoIO pluigin (GSTREAMER): glob is 'opencv_videoio_gstreamer*.dll', 1 location(s)
[ INFO:0]     - C:\opencv4.1\build\x64\vc15\bin: 0
[ INFO:0] Found 0 plugin(s) for GSTREAMER
```

(I don't want to use GStreamer, I want ffmpeg)

I tried to force OpenCV to use ffmpeg with

```
capture.open(0 + cv::CAP_FFMPEG);
```

but then it can't open the camera device.

What do I have to do that OpenCV finds ffmpeg?

Comment: Looks like, its unable to find ffmpeg library at all. Check whether avcodec (ffmpeg) file exists or not.